# Which Debian 5 and 6 mirrors are operational?

Tags: debian, repository, debian-installer

The GCC Compile Farm is migrating some old Debian machines to Debian 8.8. I'm trying to setup Debian 5 and Debian 6 for local testing to ensure continuity of coverage. I need it in my testing environment for the platform, os and compiler combination.

As I try to install Debian I keep encountering errors. For each mirror I try I get the ***`An error has been detected while trying to use the specified Debian archive mirror.`***:

[image]

Even ones that seem like they should be working are down, like `ftp.debian.org`, `ftp.us.debian.org`, `mirrors.kernel.org` and `ftp.gtlib.gatech.edu` (Georgia Tech has always been my goto).

Which Debian 5 and 6 mirrors are operational?

Comment: for debian 5 (lenny) & 6 (squeeze) and older, use archive.debian.org

Comment: Thanks @Cas. It kind of partially works. I deleted `/var/lib/apt/*`. Using `archive.debian.org`, Apt chugs along and then ... ***`E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead`*** followed by ***`404  Not Found  [IP: 193.62.202.28 80]`***. Though I have Apt 0.8, [`httpredir` is broken](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianGeoMirror). This really sucks.

Comment: can you edit your Q and add your sources.list?  It should have something like `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main`.   btw 193.62.202.28 is one of 4 A records for archive.debian.org.  i'm browsing it not and it looks OK.

Comment: Also, if you need Debian 5 and 6 for continuity, I *strongly* recommend setting up your own local mirrors and using those — that’s the only way to be absolutely sure you can re-install a system when necessary. Either that or make sure you have the full installation DVD sets of the last point release and a mirror of the corresponding security archive (although security is a bit of a moot point on old releases like those). This is true in general, for any OS — if you need a platform for production, you need to be able to re-install it without Internet access!

Answer (score 4):

Use `http://archive.debian.org/debian/`

i.e. you have to configure apt-get for Debian 6 with:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib
```

Comment: 2020 and still work!